# VBA comments in VBA editor

Tags: vba, comments

stupid question but every time I add a comment in VBA editor it adds an asterisk like this '* why is this happening and how can I stop it

Comment: For the sake of making this question useful for future visitors, it would be nice if you could [edit] your post to list what add-in you have loaded in your IDE that's causing this (normally you would comment on the answer, but you need 50 rep to comment under posts you don't own).

Answer (score 3):

Do you have a source control addin also running?  I once had something like this, somebody had written a "helper" addin that was intercepting my code and changing it.  I really do not think there are any circumstances where the native VBA environment would do this.